# How to combine the array to make an array which is coming from firestore from different documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 var emp = db.collection('BookedTicketData').get().then((snapshot) => {
                                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                                    data = doc.data();
                                    bseat = data.AllSeat
                                    // console.log(bseat)  
                                    allseat.concat(bseat)

                                })

                                    console.log(allseat)
                                return allseat;
                            }).then((alls) => {
                                     console.log(alls)
                            })
```

I have done this code to get the array from the doucumnets of firebase and it is coming seperatly i want to combine all the array in single array and print the array in console.log(alls) 
1-> [4,46,324,346,345,234,3446,36]
2-> [324,6,3,44,6,2,6,35,2,7,23]

alls -> [4,46,324,346,345,234,3446,36,3244,6,3,44,6,2,6,35,2,7,23]

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, the following should do the trick:

```
  var emp = db
    .collection('BookedTicketData')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let allseat = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        data = doc.data();
        bseat = data.AllSeat;
        // console.log(bseat)
        allseat = allseat.concat(bseat);
      });

      console.log(allseat);
      return allseat;
    })
```